# MySQL Sequelize searching two tables with one findAll

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've created 3 tables

```
Products
|product_id | product_name| 
|-----------|-------------|
|1          | coca cola   |
|2          | pepsi       |
|3          | orange      |

Product_tags
|product_id | tag_id |
|-----------|--------|
|1          | 1      |
|2          | 1      |
|3          | 2      |

Tag_names
|tag_id     | tag_name |
|-----------|----------|
|1          | soda     |
|2          | juice    |
```

Using:

```
db.products.belongsToMany(db.tag_names, { through: 'product_tags',  as: "tags", foreignKey: 'product_id'});
db.tag_names.belongsToMany(db.products, {through: 'product_tags',  as: "products", foreignKey: 'tag_id'});
```

Now I want to search these tables via either product name OR tag name. e.g. product has name "coca cola" and tag "soda" so both a search of "coca" or a search of "sod" would return it and "sod" would also return "pepsi". All I can seem to do it is get it to require both product_name and tag_name to match the query which is not what I want. 
Thanks, 
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `or` two conditions, you'll want to use the `[Op.or]` operator.  And then to access a table in a join clause from a top-level where clause, there's an interesting syntax with [dollar signs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level) that comes in handy.  I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it does return both coke and pepsi...  I tested this query in `sequelize` version 6 against a `postgres` database

```
let result = await Product.findAll({
        include: {
            model: Tag,
            as: 'tags',
            required: true
        },
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { 'product_name': { [Op.like]: '%coca%' } },
                { '$tags.tag_name$': { [Op.like]: '%sod%' } }
            ]
        }
    })
```

And using the data in the original question, it produced the following results:

```
[
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "coca cola",
    "tags": [
      {
        "tag_id": 1,
        "tag_name": "soda",
        "product_tags": {
          "createdAt": "2021-09-09T18:36:24.829Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-09-09T18:36:24.829Z",
          "product_id": 1,
          "tag_id": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_name": "pepsi",
    "tags": [
      {
        "tag_id": 1,
        "tag_name": "soda",
        "product_tags": {
          "createdAt": "2021-09-09T18:36:24.861Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-09-09T18:36:24.861Z",
          "product_id": 2,
          "tag_id": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Along with this query:

```
SELECT          "product"."product_id",
                "product"."product_name",
                "tags"."tag_id" AS "tags.tag_id",
                "tags"."tag_name" AS "tags.tag_name",
                "tags->product_tags"."created_at" AS "tags.product_tags.createdAt",
                "tags->product_tags"."updated_at" AS "tags.product_tags.updatedAt",
                "tags->product_tags"."product_id" AS "tags.product_tags.product_id",
                "tags->product_tags"."tag_id" AS "tags.product_tags.tag_id"
FROM            "products" AS "product" INNER JOIN (
                        "product_tags" AS "tags->product_tags" INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tags"
                            ON "tags"."tag_id" = "tags->product_tags"."tag_id"
                    ) ON "product"."product_id" = "tags->product_tags"."product_id"
WHERE           ("product"."product_name" LIKE '%coca%' OR
                "tags"."tag_name" LIKE '%sod%');
```